# Iterate Graphical Model over a set of numbers in a non geometric layer

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, qgis-modeler, iteration

I have built a Graphical Model which, among other actions, extracts attributes of a vector layer by using the 'Extract by Attribute' algorithm. The extracted features are those whose Time in the Date&Time field lies within one specific hour of a day (say between 08:00 and 09:00) and then certain operations are performed on them. I was trying to iterate the Model to perform this over every hour of the day in a loop. So it would start from 00:00 to 00:59, then 01:00 to 01:59...and so on till 23:00 to 23:59.

I tried to use Vector Features as an input since this can be iterated. The vector feature referred to a CSV file which had only one field of 'Hours'. This field has 23 rows which were integer values (epoch values of hours).

I wanted to give each feature of this CSV file as an iterative input to the Extract as Attribute function and was to use it in the 'Formula' to incrementally increase the hours to be picked up.

However, the values are not being picked up. I tried to experiment with a simple model which used 'Field Calculator' to insert a new field with the current value of the Feature. however, here again, the new field does not contain any value. Just not able to get it to work.

Model -
[image]

If I keep the formula as Value, I get 'Null' in the New field, if I keep it as 'pre-calculated value', I get an error 'No root node! Parsing failed?'. In another case, I got an error'Cannot convert to feature' I think when I was using it directly in a formula to modify time.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: We are not yet able to refer to another model layer than the Field Calculator algorithm input in the expression: https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/30397

Comment: Thank you so much! This does explain why I am facing the issue. Would you be aware of any workaround? I know we can probably do this from a Py script, but I would like to use the GUI of the Modeler, makes feeding the inputs easier.

Comment: A workaround is create one model with all the process for any hour, and one model with 23 algorithms that call the other model with each hour as parameter.

Comment: Brilliant! I think that may just work for me!! Thanks so much! Really appreciate it!